# Cluster Analysis in R: Elbow Method in K-means

Tags: r, cluster-analysis, k-means

I'm implementing the elbow method to my data set using the R package fviz_nbclust. This method will calculate the total within sum square of each cluster by varying K from 1.....k. For example the elbow method suggest K=2. Say we have here two different results for K-means alone. Is there a way to find out which wss did the elbow method calculated? Is there a possible way to view which K-means result the elbow method used in clustered using K=2?

[image]

[image]

Comment: Please create a MWE as suggested here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269/how-to-make-a-great-r-reproducible-example

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There might be more elegant methods but you could simply add out-of-scope assignment to your cluster function, e.g.:

```
l <- list()
f <- function(...) {
  km <- kmeans(...)
  l[[nrow(km$centers)]] <<- km
  km
}

fviz_nbclust(df, f, method = "wss", k.max = 10)
```

Then simply index `l[[optimal nr of clusters]]` to retrieve the model

Comment: Thanks for this answer. I wonder why nobody gave it an upvote